# Cookie not saved on localhost in browser, but Set-Cookie header exists in response

Tags: node.js, cookies, jwt

I see many similar topics opened, but none did it for me.

I use React TS on Front End and Node + Express on Back End.

I have post routes to login and register to my site, and am successfully logging in and registering accounts, that works fine.

Now, when logging in / registering I want to set a cookie so that I can use it for Auth and session's that won't ask the user for the password until his credentials until the cookie expires.

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:5173",
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    credentials: true,
  })
)
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cookieParser())

const JWTsecret = process.env.JWT_SECRET
```

//

```
  const token = jwt.sign({ user: user.id }, JWTsecret, { expiresIn: "1h" })

  console.log("Generated token: ", token)
  res.cookie("user", token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    domain: "localhost",
    path: "/",
    maxAge: 1000000000,
  })
  res.status(200).json(user)
```

This is how add the cookie I see that a token is generated, I see Set-Cookie and it's value is present in the res header, but no matter what I do, It doesn't want to stick in the browser so that I could use it and validate it.

I only send the cookie if all the checks and credentials are ok.

.env is working correctly, data get's fetched correctly, everything else works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Providing a cookie in the response is only part of the problem.  You also need to store the cookie in the app state in your front end.

```js
document.cookie = 'myCookieKey=myCookieValue; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 2022 00:00:00 UTC; path=/';
```

Then you will need to read the cookie to send your token back to the server.  Here is a basic example showing how to read and set your cookie.

```js
import React from 'react';

const CookieExample = () => {
  const readCookie = () => {
    // Read the entire cookie string
    const cookieString = document.cookie;

    // Parse the cookie string into individual cookies
    const cookies = cookieString.split(';').map(cookie => cookie.trim());

    // Place cookies in a map
    const cookiesMap = []
    cookies.forEach(cookie => {
      const [cookieKey, cookieValue] = cookie.split("=")
      cookiesMap[cookieKey] = cookieValue
    })

    // Output cookieMap
    console.log(cookiesMap)
  };

  const setCookie = () => {
    // Set a cookie with a key-value pair and an expiration date
    document.cookie = 'user=some-token; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 2025 00:00:00 UTC; path=/';
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={readCookie}>Read Cookie</button>
      <button onClick={setCookie}>Set Cookie</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CookieExample;
```

Comment: So should I return the cookie from the backend then? and then using document.cookie to set it, instead of just my res.cookie - which in turn just says that the response should contain a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Found the bug, If someone else is going from code that is for production mode, to code that is for development mode (basically when doing tests, you run your server and website on localhost), then you must change all the axios/fetch/ajax requests you're making to your production domain, to localhost, make sure not to miss any of them because that was it for me.